# Connect to DynamoDB using NoSQL Workbench and the IAM role ARN option

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect to **DynamoDB** using **NoSQL Workbench** and the last option i.e. **IAM role ARN**, but I am getting the following error:

*Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1*
How to fix this error?

Moreover,
The pre-requisites for using an IAM role are not clear. I have the following queries

1. Do we use IAM role ARN in combination with our temporary credentials?
2. Do we use the IAM role option in combination with our IAM credentials?
3. Do we create a role, then the policy, and then assign it to our IAM user?
4. How to get a working IAM role ARN for connecting to DynamoDB using NoSQL workbench?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue - any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide all the fields that are marked with * as required, they are Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.

- If you are using [temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) you will need to specify a session token. Remember temporary credentials have a timeout and you will need to re-issue a token when they expire.
- If not, you can specify the role ARN that you will use you are You can also specify the role that you will assume with the credentials that you have provided initially.

About your questions:

1. No you don't when you assume a role with temporary credentials you don't have to provide additional role, (unless you want it and actually have the permissions to do it so).
2. Yes if you are not using temporary credentials you use the role only with your IAM credentials.
3. You can do it this way but if you want to keep policies separated to use them in other roles, you can do , first policy, then role, and then assign to the user or group.
4. You create a policy (this policy needs to have access to DynamoDB resources), you create a role and assign the policy that you have created before, and you then assign this role to the user.

It is best practices to work with temporary credentials as if they are compromised for some reason they will be only available for the duration of the token, I recommend you give it a read to this section of the documentation [temporary security credentials in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html).

I hope it helps!